# Type mismatch setting file equals, opening Word file,

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Excel macro crashes when trying to open Word File

I have tried with the target file open and closed. Both files are in the folder.
I have added the following Object Models to the project: Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.

```
    Sub CopyCheckBoxesToWord()
        CopyCheckBoxesToWord Macro
        'http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2012/01/copy-from-excel-and-paste-in-word/
        Dim objWord As Word.Application
        Set objWord = "Example.docx" 'Error Type mismatch here
        'Word file is in the same folder as the excel file.  I have it 
        'open.
        Range("G5").Copy
        With objWord
           .Documents.Add
           .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
           .Visible = True
        End With
        End Sub
```

I want to access the file.  It can be open or closed, but open is better.
I want to write the contents of G5 to the Word file in unformatted unicode text.

Comment: Hi. to open a Word documento u can jus t do Documents.Open FileName:="C:\MyFiles\MyDoc.doc"

Comment: Can you share the document?

Answer (score 1):

The type mismatch is because you have declared `objWord` as type `Word.Application` and you are trying to set it to a `String` value

Perhaps something like:

```
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document


Set objWord = New Word.Application
With objWord
    Set objDoc = .Documents.Open("Example.docx")
    … *your code*

End With
```

Comment: I added Dim objDoc As Word.Document,Dim Selection As String,With objWord
    .Set objDoc = "GeneratorCheckBoxes.docx"
    .Selection = Range("H5").Select
    .Documents.Add
    .Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=xlPasteText
    .Visible = True
End With

Comment: Still crashes at line with file name.

Comment: @Chas what do you mean by **crashes**?

Comment: @Chas look up the syntax for Documents.Open and use the code provided in the answer above - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open

Comment: @Chas be careful not to confuse Excel and Word objects and methods. You can’t use xlPasteText when using a Word paste method.

Comment: @Chas And in your almost impossible to read paste of code into a comment, I don't see where you've `Set objWord` to anything.